# Составить программу для определения значения функции

Tags: c, инспекция-кода

Составить программу для определения значения функции. Предусмотреть вывод
сообщения о том, по какой ветви происходило вычисление значения аргумента
функции х.
[image: zadacha]

Я не очень силён в математике, не могли бы вы указать на ошибки, которые я допустил?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main() {
    double x,y,z,k;
    printf("k value: \n");
    scanf("%lf", &k);
    printf("z value: \n");
    scanf("%lf", &z);
    if (k<1) {
        x = k * pow(z, 3);
        y = pow( log(1+pow(x,2.0)) + cos(x+1)  ,exp(k*x));
        printf("%5.5lf", y);
    } else {
        x = z * (z+1);
        y = pow( log(1+pow(x,2.0)) + cos(x+1)  ,exp(k*x));
        printf("%5.5lf", y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основное вычисление у вас -

```
if (k<1) {
    x = k * pow(z, 3);
    y = pow( log(1+pow(x,2.0)) + cos(x+1)  ,exp(k*x));
    printf("%5.5lf", y);
} else {
    x = z * (z+1);
    y = pow( log(1+pow(x,2.0)) + cos(x+1)  ,exp(k*x));
    printf("%5.5lf", y);
}
```

Но обратите внимание: две последние строки в каждой ветви идентичны. Почему бы не сделать так:

```
if (k<1) {
    x = k * pow(z, 3);
} else {
    x = z * (z+1);
}
y = pow( log(1+pow(x,2.0)) + cos(x+1)  ,exp(k*x));
printf("%5.5lf", y);
```

Ну, я бы переписал все примерно как

```
x = z*((k<1) ? k*z*z : z+1);
y = pow(log(x*x+1)+cos(x+1),exp(k*x));
```

но это уже не принципиально.

Ах, да - у вас еще требуют вывод ветви...

```
printf("%5.5lf - ветвь %s", y, (k<1) ? "k<1" : "k>=1");
```

Конкретный `%5.5lf` оставляю вам - вам виднее, как требуется выводить значения. Я бы написал просто `%lf`, если никаких требований нет.

Раз у вас очень большие значения - используйте научную нотацию:

```
printf("%lg - ветвь %s", y, (k<1) ? "k<1" : "k>=1");
```

Да, и еще! `int main`, не `void main`!

Comment: Спасибо, учту, но меня скорее смущает результат, который выводится. При  k = 1, z = 2, ответ = 15165424421509362000000000(много нулей).000000. Еще раз повторюсь, что в математике не силен:)

Comment: Давайте прикинем. При ваших значениях x = 6, логарифм+косинус - примерно 4.6, e^(kx) - 403. 4.6 в степени 403 - это 267-значное число. Похоже на правду. Думаю, что z у вас должно быть куда меньше 1 :)  См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: мое почтение! поэтому и уточнял, что не силен в математике, теперь все стало на свои места. Спасибо за уделенное мне время, я обязательно учту это в будущем)

Comment: вот на счет int main и void main хотел уточнить, как раз задавался этим вопросом минут 10 назад, почему все таки int? Зачем лишняя строка с return 0? Спасибо.

Comment: `return 0` из `main` не обязательна, а вот `int main` - это обязательно, это стандарт...